# Which tense should I use when presenting a table of data?

Tags: tenses, past-vs-present, paragraphs, research

I have a table and the description of the table as followed:

[image]

> Table 7 presents the likelihood of OPT occurrences from the time
>   annotated sentences; V-RB refers to the sentences which contain
>   post-verbal adverbs and RB-V refers to the sentences which contain
>   pre-verbal adverbs. The OPT phenomenon manifested 68.18% of the time
>   when an already or yesterday adverb was present in the sentence in the
>   ICE-SIN.

Within the paragraphs, my tenses were inconsistent. When i present the table and how to read the table I used present tense. But when I wanted to described the phenomenon that was recorded in the data, I used the past tense.

**Is the inconsistent tenses grammatical? Or should I use the past tense when I present the table and how to read the table?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are ***presenting*** the table, you are doing it *now*, i.e. in the **present** time. The clue is in the word ***PRESENTing***. But the table itself contains data that has already been collected - in the past.

So you are correct in ***presenting*** the table in the *present* tense, but ***discussing*** the *previously collected* data in the *past* tense.